Matplotlib animation script runs fine first time but gets stuck on re-runs until kernel is restarted
I'm trying to run an animation where a scatter plot is updated every timestep. I am working in a jupyter notebook in vscode (if relevant). The animation script, given below, runs great the first time but it doesn't execute as intended on subsequent runs. The problem is only fixed when I restart the kernel. My work requires me to constantly modify this animation code and hence need to rerun it multiple times. Restarting the kernel every time is cumbersome.
In following code (edited to make executable), I am plotting object locations (block_centroids) using a scatter plot and updating them using the displacements at time timepoints[i] (given by fields[i]).
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
%matplotlib ipympl
%matplotlib widget
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

# Toy example

timepoints = np.arange(0,1,0.02)    # 100 frames

xs = np.arange(1,11)
ys = np.arange(1,11)
block_centroids = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(xs, ys)).reshape(-1, 2) 
# (N, 2) initial location array for N = 100 objects

rand_amp = np.random.rand(100, 2)/10
fields = [rand_amp * np.sin(i/(20*np.pi)) for i in range(len(timepoints))] 
# sinusoidal displacements for each object with random amplitudes

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,5), tight_layout = True)

scat = axes.scatter(xs, ys)
axes.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

def update(val):
    if val == len(timepoints) - 1:
        print('closing!')
        exit()

    scat.set_offsets(block_centroids + fields[val])
    fig.suptitle(fr'time $t = {timepoints[val]:.2f}$s')
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    return scat

def init():
    pass

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=update, init_func=init, frames=len(timepoints), blit = True, interval=100)

After the first time I run this code block, the re-run either gets stuck at some midway time (between 0s and 1s) and prematurely prints 'closing!', or the code keeps running seemingly forever with no output and no error until I try to stop it and the kernel times out.
I have tried multiple things without completely understanding why they might work. My guess is that the animation-related objects are not reset and somehow the update() function gets called with the wrong (old) value and my attempts have mostly tried to close/delete the old instances.

I added the if statement inside the update() function in an attempt to close the animation after a run. Earlier, instead of the exit() function, I was using plt.close(fig) which led to the animation getting stuck at a midway time and printing 'closing!' output repeatedly.

I tried adding plt.cla(), plt.clf() and plt.close() at the start of the code block to close any open instances of fig and axes but that didn't help.

I tried deleting the fig and ani objects using del command to remove their previous instances in hopes of getting a fresh start for every run but that didn't work.

Earlier even the first runs of the animation were having problems. I added Agg backend after reading a stackoverflow answer recommending GTKAgg for handling animations better. I couldn't use GTKAgg because I don't have cairo, so I settled for the closest thing and that helped is making the first run successful.


What is not working here as intended? What can I try to debug this? I tried printing val at every function call, to check what is happening during reruns but then the code kept running without any output.

you need to clear the graph before updating, otherwise new plots will be added on top of the old plot

You seem to be using non-current coding approaches. What flavor and version of Jupyter are you using specifically? A lot of what you mention about point #2 and point #4 are outdated and poor advice in the current landscape. Plus you have no references to this advice here so we could check how current it is? Please don't use current tech with old code and advice. It is a recipe for trouble. As for re-running being cumbersome. One solution for this is to collect the frames as it runs and make a player that will play it in later runs via a controller. If done correctly it even runs as a ...

 'static' saved notebook when run in nbviewer. Here is an example you can play using a controller. This was made a while back though and so some of the approaches are easier. See here if you using very current Jupyter tech and here for old tech. You can launch sessions for either using 'launch binder' on the appropriate page. There's several examples related to ...

 animation.FuncAnimation() use there or in related code.

@Wayne I couldn't find my jupyter version but my guess it should be current if my python version is 3.9.6. Weirdly "jupyter command is not found" on zsh.

When you are in Jupyter, there should be an 'About' or something along that line, under the 'Help' menu entry along the top menubar that begins with 'File'. Note if it says JupyterLab or Jupyter Notebook. You can also see here for pointers on visual cues you can use when you are running Jupyter these days. Python 3.9.6 is quite old at almost 3 years old at this point. More importantly, Jupyter and Python on your system are two different beasts. The age of one is in no way enlightening about the other.

And about, 'Weirdly "jupyter command is not found" on zsh.' How do you normally start up Jupyter then? I'm wondering if you use the Anaconda distribution then? The tiles in the Anaconda Navigator will often show the versions in the base install.

@Wayne I love the controller you have shown in that link but I don't get what method in the code is responsible for it.
Btw by cumbersome reruns, I was referring to how I will typically change something in the animation-plot code (say the marker style) and want to rerun to see this change. I don't exactly see how a player with a controller gets around that issue.

@Wayne for jupyter version: I created a jupyter notebook in vscode workspace using the "jupyter extension for vscode". So the "File" and "About" are for vscode and not jupyter. Checking the packages in finder (mac's file explorer), I see the jupyter packages in an env in the same parent directory as my workspace. Btw I really appreciate the help and patience!

Oh yes, sorry. You did say this was VSCode. So that is the Jupyter Extension and it is definitely going to be pertinent. If you look at here under 'Working with Python', it says you needed to have installed Jupyter in your Python environment. And so that is where you are seeing the Jupyter packages you mention. I wonder if you can trigger to run those directly in some way because testing there would give you a better understanding of what it possible. It may be exactly the same, it may now. I don't use VSCode for ...

 animations and so it is hard to be able to say if everything that works in Jupyter direct will or won't work in VSCode? This makes me think what I use here with %matplotlib ipympl is what you want to model your code after and expect to work. And that you don't need matplotlib.use('Agg'). Let me see if I can convert you code to work in sessions launched from here so that I can show you what I think should work.

So... running your code gives NameError: name 'block_centroids' is not defined. And so this is not a self-contained code block you have provided making it hard to provide specifics close to your code. In the future, provide code that runs as advised under the section 'Help others reproduce the problem' about a minimal, reproducible example in How do I ask a good question?. I'm going to try and hack a little more but if I have to deviate further from your code it becomes more frustrating and less likely to help you with your issue. I see you at...

 explained what the code about the block_centroids involves and what should happen in the plot but ideally it would be a toy example that worked to the degree it ran but still encountered the issue that lead you to post, about needing to restart the kernel.

You should be explicityly using %matplotlib ipympl. The documentation is clear that %matplotlib widget is an alternative for the same thing, see here. You get a warning if you put another %matplotlib after it, even if it is moot. Because the name matches with the package needed, the %matplotlib ipympl is better as it is explicit, which is emphasized in line 2 of the Zen of Python.

5000 points is not a minimal, reproducible example. Plus with your updated code, I see RuntimeError: The init_func must return a sequence of Artist objects. I stuck with one I made from your code and mine that has three points.

@Wayne Thanks and sorry, I will amend the code. I ran your FuncAnimation-based code with widget controller in my vscode notebook. It still shows the standard interactive plot widget as usual for me but not the controller with pause/play options. The reruns are slightly better and always show the plot animation but with random restarts in between and switching between the previous and current runs (I checked by using different plot label formatting in each run).

This code should let you see if VSCode is capable of what I am describing with making a controller that you can use instead of re-rerunning all the calculations. (This is no guarantee it will work with your data because you still need to save all the frames as part of the notebook.) However, it will allow you to understand maybe how you could in theory approach this in VSCode if the same code works.
It makes three points in a scatter plot.
A Jupyter notebook with related code already run is here.  (You'll note that even though that is a 'static' rendering of the code of the notebook, the controller at the bottom of the nbviewer-rendered page works, see more about this below the second code block.)
Demonstrate making these two animations in active Jupyter: Click here to launch that notebook in an active, temporary Jupyter session served via MyBinder.org with the environment already having Python everything needed to make the animation with a widget work in the notebook installed and working.
1. This first code block corresponds to top plot in the linked notebooks and it just runs if you run it and then stops
Plot animation that you can run to repeat is below. Make this code block a new cell in a new notebook in your VSCode all its own and try it:
%matplotlib ipympl
# based on OP's code & code currently next to 'In [6]' at https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/animated_matplotlib-binder/blob/main/index.ipynb , adapted from https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/matplotlib-animation-not-appearing-in-jupyter-notebook/24938/3?u=fomightez
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

tstep = 1
#xs, ys = block_centroids.T
xs, ys = (1,4,6),(2,5,9)
timepoints = list(zip(xs,ys))
points = list(zip(xs,ys))
num_steps = len(timepoints)

#print(points)
#print(np.arange(0, num_steps))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.85)


def animate(frame):
    step_num = frame % (num_steps)
    ax.scatter(points[step_num][0],points[step_num][1], c='skyblue', s=60)
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_title(f"frame: {frame} ; step_num: {step_num} ; {points[step_num][0]}; {points[step_num][1]}")  
    ax.grid(True)
    
    return ax

fig.suptitle(f"animation with {len(timepoints)} timepoints and setting of tsteps = {tstep}.")
#ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames= np.arange(0, num_steps), interval = 1000, repeat = False)
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames= 3, interval = 1000, repeat = False)
ani;

That code block above is essentially our starting point and is something along the lines of what OP was posting about trying to implement.
However, the matplotlib FuncAnimation() has ability to make frames that can run via a controller. This makes replay of the animation easier! The next cell in the associated notebook and the code below is to show how just slight changes to the above code can enable this ability.
2. Add playback widget controller: the block below corresponds to second cell in linked notebook
So you can make a controller, you can just add a couple lines and remove the ending ; (Note the warning at the top of ignore the extra static frame or re-run), make this a cell in a notebook all on its own and try running it:
# If upon first running, it shows a non-interactive, single static shot of the plot below the interactive one with the widget controller,
# JUST RE-RUN TWICE. Re-run usually fixes that display quirk.
%matplotlib ipympl
# based on OP's code & code currently next to 'In [6]' at https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/animated_matplotlib-binder/blob/main/index.ipynb , adapted from https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/matplotlib-animation-not-appearing-in-jupyter-notebook/24938/3?u=fomightez
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
plt.rcParams["animation.html"] = "jshtml"
plt.ioff() #needed so the second time you run it you get only single plot

tstep = 1
#xs, ys = block_centroids.T
xs, ys = (1,4,6),(2,5,9)
timepoints = list(zip(xs,ys))
points = list(zip(xs,ys))
num_steps = len(timepoints)

#print(points)
#print(np.arange(0, num_steps))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.85)


def animate(frame):
    step_num = frame % (num_steps)
    ax.scatter(points[step_num][0],points[step_num][1], c='skyblue', s=60)
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_title(f"frame: {frame} ; step_num: {step_num} ; {points[step_num][0]}; {points[step_num][1]}")  
    ax.grid(True)
    
    return ax

fig.suptitle(f"animation with {len(timepoints)} timepoints and setting of tsteps = {tstep}.")
#ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames= np.arange(0, num_steps), interval = 1000, repeat = False)
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames= 3, interval = 1000, repeat = False)
ani

Two background references for output of FuncAnimation()-generated animation to frames with javascript based controller widget or to HTML5 that better explain it and were where I learned about it:

Embedding Matplotlib Animations in Jupyter as Interactive JavaScript Widgets

Embedding Matplotlib Animations in IPython Notebooks


Those animations frames and associated controller can be viewed in nbviewer using the controller widget, too!

See for yourself:
A Jupyter notebook with related code already run is here. Hit the play button there at that link to play the pre-made animation!
You'll note that even though that is a 'static' rendering of the code of the notebook, the controller at the bottom of the nbviewer-rendered page works because when the cell is run in a Jupyter session the data is recorded in the notebook file. When the notebook is saved in that session and then downloaed and placed online, you can view the notebook and its output subsequently with the Jupyter Community's nbviewer and the javascript-based playback controller widget added by Matplotlib is still functional when the notebook is rendered that way and you can playback the animation without even being in Jupyter . The notebook is actually stored on GitHub, yet GitHub's preview rendering won't allow playback.

OKAY, this worked great! The controller worked and I can rerun it without having any issues. But I don't understand it yet. Setting rcparams animation.html to jshtml is what gives the widget controller, right? And the controller is kinda saving the animation and using a player to display it, which somehow solves the problem in rerunning. It no longer wrongfully calls the previous run's update function, I guess?

Yes, sorry. I'll explain it better and provide a link to the historic record description of the process. It was in what I linked to, and I should include it here. The data from the frames gets saved, too. An so if you go to the bottom of the SAVED notebook file rendered via nbviewer, you can still use the controller because it is javascrupt based and the frame image data is in the notebook. nbviewer just points at the github version of this notebook, the github preview version won't display the controller.

I added references that walk you through the expanded output options of FuncAnimation()-generated animations.

Thanks a ton! Also wanted to confirm that the output options work with jupyter extension in vscode. I didn't need to change anything to make it work.
